# Unable to Replace a Dask Series Partition

Tags: dask, dask-delayed

I'm trying to replace a Series dask partition with my own partition.
I've used the code snippet given by [@MRocklin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/616616/mrocklin) in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51100606/replace-a-dask-dataframe-partition/51101017#51101017) post.

```
list_of_delayed = dask_df.to_delayed()
new_partition = dask.delayed(pd.read_csv)(filename)
list_of_delayed[i] = new_partition
new_dask_df = dd.from_delayed(list_of_delayed, meta=dask_df._meta)
```

I've done exactly the same except dask_df is a series in my case. I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "sdfr_dhruvkmr.py", line 465, in <module>
    pts = task[(task.task_date <= dtm.Time.iloc[i]) & (task.T_Date == dtm.Date.iloc[i])]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/edask/dataframe.py", line 130, in __getitem__
    new_dask_df = dd.from_delayed(list_of_delayed)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/edask/edask/dask/dataframe/io/io.py", line 493, in from_delayed
    type(df).__name__)
TypeError: Expected Delayed object, got Delayed
```

Comment: I recommend making an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: See http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2016/08/25/supporting-users